# database context manager and query execution exception handling

Tags: python, database, contextmanager

I would like to connect to a database, execute a query inside a context manager and handle the exceptions

```
import pyodbc

class db_connection(object):

    def __init__(self, connection_string):
        self.connection_string = connection_string
        self.connector = None

    def __enter__(self):
        print("connecting to DB ...")
        try:
            self.connector = pyodbc.connect(self.connection_string)
        except Exception:
            print("connection failed")
        else:
            print("connected")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb): 
        pass 

    def runQuery(self, query):
        result_list = None
        if self.connector == None:
            pass
        else:
            try:
                cursor = self.connector.cursor()
                result_list = cursor.execute(query).fetchall() 
            except Exception:
                print("query failed")
            finally:
                return result_list
```

To call this class like so:

```
connect_string = "DRIVER={ODBC SQL};SERVER=LOCALSERVER;DATABASE=LOCALDB; Trusted_Connection=yes"
query = "SELECT ALL FROM LOCALDB"

with db_connection(connect_string) as connection:
    connection.runQuery(query)
```

With two questions (besides the fact I am not to sure this is a decent pythonic solution):

1 - I don't seem to need the _ *exit* _ statement at all

2 - The runQuery() method needs to be called separately, is it possible to also include this in the _ *enter* _ statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pythonic way would be to close in the *_ exit _* statement the resource you opened in the *_ enter _* statement (to prevent memory leaks etc). But connections are meant to be **reused** so we don't need to close them everytime. If you want to reuse connections try researching how connection pooling works in pyodbc and if you don't then close the connection in the  *_ exit _* method. Anyway you still need  the *_ exit _* method to fulfill the context manager protocol. In your case the *_ exit _* statement manages exceptions.

I don't think that including the runQuery() method in in the *_ enter _* statement is a good idea.

```
# !BAD example
with db_connection_run_query(connect_string, query) as query_result:
    ...
```

Query_result is just a list of Rows - you don't need a context manager to work with it.

BTW your runQuery method doesn't close the cursor. This is also a potential memory leak. You need to close it in the finally clause before returning the result. (context manager might also help here)

```
try:
    cursor = self.connector.cursor()
    result_list = cursor.execute(query).fetchall() 
except Exception:
    print("query failed")
finally:
    cursor.close()
    return result_list
```

One more thing. Your runQuery method will only work with select queries and not with inserts, updates and deletes (To perform those you need to commit a transaction by calling commit() on cursor). So you may consider renaming runQuery to runSelectQuery.

Answer (score 1):

here is the final result, case you are interested:

```
import pyodbc

class db_connection(object):
    """database connection class"""

    def __init__(self, connection_string):
        self.connection_string = connection_string
        self.__connector = None
        self.__query_result_OK = False

    def __enter__(self):
        print("connecting to DB ... ", end="")
        try:
            self.__connector = pyodbc.connect(self.connection_string)
        except pyodbc.InterfaceError as ife:
            ife.__str__ = ("connection failed, pdobc interface exception: probably the connection string has syntax errors")
            print(ife.__str__, end="")
            return ife
        except pyodbc.OperationalError as ore:
            ore.__str__ = ("connection failed, pdobc operational exception: keywords missing, needs DRIVER, SERVER, DATABASE")
            print(ore.__str__, end="")
            return ore
        except Exception as rest:
            print(str(rest.__class__), end="")
        else:
            print("connected")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.__connector == None:
            pass
        else:
            if self.__query_result_OK == False:
                print("rolling back")
                self.__connector.rollback()
            else:
                print("query executed correctly")
            self.__connector.close()
            print("connection closed")

    def runQuery(self, query):
        local_result_list = None
        if self.__connector == None:
            pass
        else:
            try:
                cursor = self.__connector.cursor()
                local_result_list = cursor.execute(query).fetchall() # cursor query result into list
                local_result_list.reverse() # oldest on top, newest at the bottom
                self.__query_result_OK = True
            except Exception:
                print("query failed")
            finally:
                cursor.close()
                return local_result_list

# EOF
```